# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client erro when i ask the same route for 2nd time? (Always)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am now trying to write a update function in mongoose.
My code is like this

```
app.patch("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {

  let _id = req.params.id;
  if (_id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
    try {
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send("User not found");
      }
      res.send(user);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  }
  res.send("error format");
});
```

As you can see i am using path method to update the obj.
The problem is on this line

```
if (_id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
```

When ever i try to match the object id, On the 2nd calls I always get this error. Can Someone explain why?

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

If I remove this if statement the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to exit from a handler after `res.send(user)`.

```
if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send("User not found");
      }
res.send(user);
return;
```

Without `return` your code continues to execute and next line will be `res.send("error format");`